# Unable to set Custom Classloader as default classloader in java

Tags: java, jar, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I am working on some usecase where i want that my custom classloader should be used instead of the default system classloader. For this i tried many ways

1. `java -Djava.system.class.loader=org.example.loader.CCLoader -jar <path to app jar>.jar`
2. `java -Djava.system.class.loader=<complete path to compiled CCLoader>.class -jar <path to app jar>.jar`
3. `java -Djava.system.class.loader=<complete path to CCLoader>.java -jar <path to app jar>.jar`
4. `java -Djava.system.class.loader=org.example.loader.CCL.CCLoader -cp <path to app jar>.jar org.example.App`

Again and again i am getting `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:` on **CCLoader**.

Even after unzipping the app.jar, i could find the CCLoader.

I don't know where i am getting this wrong.

**Edit**: Added stacktrace for reference, And yes the CCLoader is in the same jar as of now just to check but later i will move the CCLoader in some other jar and use it from there.

**Edit2**: corrected path of the CCLoader.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /Users/gouravkumar/Desktop/KPOCs/Class_Isolation_Loading/setCustomCL/target/classes/org/example/CCL/CC_Loader.class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1462)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1429)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /Users/gouravkumar/Desktop/KPOCs/Class_Isolation_Loading/setCustomCL/target/classes/org/example/CCL/CC_Loader.class
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at java.lang.SystemClassLoaderAction.run(ClassLoader.java:2202)
        at java.lang.SystemClassLoaderAction.run(ClassLoader.java:2188)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1449)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1429)
```

Comment: Could you provide particular stacktrace containing missing class name? System classloader has to set parents e.g. bootstrap and extension classloaders.

Comment: i would assume that CCLoader is yours? are you providing the CCLoader class in your jar file?

Comment: I have edited my post please have a look. Just now i found out that using `javac -J-Djava.class.path=<path to app jar>.jar -J-Djava.system.class.loader=org.example.CCL.CCLoader 
` the CCLoader is getting triggered. but i don't know whether this is right or not.

Comment: At first, fully qualified classname is different in the example ```-Djava.system.class.loader=org.example.loader.CCLoade``` and the stacktrace ```/org/example/CCL/CC_Loader```. Finally Java is case sensitive, so capital package names are not the good choice.

Comment: my bad, i wrote the package name, it has been corrected now. Please suggest some solution. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn’t help to change the command line options in the question on Stackoverflow. To the JVM only what you actually specified to the command matters. According to the exception, it was `/Users/gouravkumar/Desktop/KPOCs/Class_Isolation_Loading/setCustomCL/target/classes/org/example/CCL/CC_Loader.class` instead of `org.example.loader.CCL.CCLoader`.